# SAR and elevation models

Tags: dem, insar

Is an existing Digital Elevation Model (DEM) necessary to process Synthetic Aperture Radar (SAR) imagery?

From [earthdata](https://hyp3-docs.asf.alaska.edu/dems/) it seems a DEM is necessary. It uses the 30-meter: GLO-30 Copernicus DEM to create Radiometric Terrain Correction (RTC) and Interferometric SAR (InSAR) products.

I was under the impression SAR can create a DEM through the InSAR procedure.
Is an existing elevation model necessary to process SAR imagery?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary. You can read that at the description of following link: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S1_GRD

Comment: You are very kind to respond so promptly @xunilk. Thank you. Does the resolution of the DEM increase the quality of the SAR products? If I should ask a separate question, please advise.

Comment: Yes, of course. You can complement with this information: https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/toolboxes/sentinel-1

Comment: Ok. I think I understand. InSAR converts the phase difference between two images to 'relative' values. A DEM is necessary to determine absolute height. DInSAR can monitor subsistence/motion/lift though subtracting an exisiting DEM from the interferometric phase. page 28-31 [https://www.esa.int/esapub/tm/tm19/TM-19_ptA.pdf]